# Same key multiple times for groupby

Tags: python, iterator, group-by

I don't think that I found out a bug but it doesn't look normal to me.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
c=[((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'one'), 
   ((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'two'), 
   ((u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value'), u'one'), 
   ((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'three'), 
   ((u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value'), u'two')]
b= groupby(c, key=itemgetter(0))
for unique_keys, group in b:
    print unique_keys
```

Yields:

```
(u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value')
(u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value')
(u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value')
(u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value')
```

Any explanations ? (I was expecting only two different keys). I am using python 2.7.1 if that makes a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterable needs to already be sorted (on the same key function):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
c=[((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'one'), 
   ((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'two'), 
   ((u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value'), u'one'), 
   ((u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value'), u'three'), 
   ((u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value'), u'two')]
b= groupby(sorted(c,key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))
for unique_keys, group in b:
    print unique_keys
```

out:

```
(u'http://www.example.com', u'second_value')
(u'http://www.hello.com', u'second_value')
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot, I can't upvote your answer for now because I don't have >15 reputation. There's not really a warning on the doc page. That's not something that one would except considering most other groupby functions in other languages/library don't require this.

Comment: @thg435 -- I will try not to overuse it, thanks for the edit.